# Play a song selected from a dropdownlist in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, audio, drop-down-menu

I'm using 'label1' like a global variable to pass info from 1 script (type="text/javascript") to another script (runat="server"), however the setAttribute("src",...) with a variable doesn't seem to work. Note that it does work if hardcoded. Here is a portion of my ASP.Net code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var soundObject = null;
    function PlaySound() {
        if (soundObject != null) {
            document.body.removeChild(soundObject);
            soundObject.removed = true;
            soundObject = null;
        }
        soundObject = document.createElement("embed");
        soundObject.setAttribute("src", label1.Text);
        soundObject.setAttribute("hidden", true);
        soundObject.setAttribute("autostart", true);
        document.body.appendChild(soundObject);
    }
    window.onload = PlaySound;
    </script>

    <script runat="server" >    
        void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = SongList.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
            Response.Write(SongList.SelectedItem.Value);
        }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList id="SongList" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Selection_Change" 
runat="server">
              <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Love Is All Around.mp3">
Love Is All Around.mp3</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="Om.mp3">Om.mp3</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="Nights In White Satin.mp3">
Nights In White Satin.mp3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label ID="label1" Text="Om.mp3" runat="server" />
<input type="button" onclick="PlaySound()" value="Play Sound" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, that your javascript does not find the `label1` variable.

You can not just reference asp.net server controls in javascript - javascript doesn't know about them.

Find your `label1` via javascript with `getElementById` and then read the content of the element (in javascript this will be a `span`). The `ID` you use in `getElementById` has to be the `ClientID` of your label, so if you want to use `label1` for an id, you need to set the `ClientIDMode` property to `static`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Note I didn't need the span. I simply: var song = document.getIdByElement("label1); and changed the setAttribute from label1.Text to song.InnetText. And then lastly where label1 was defined, I added the ClientIdMode="static" attribute.